# MLE on Structural VAR / DSGE

Tags: dsge, structural-estimation, reduced-form-estimation, svar

I have a simple DSGE model that I wish to fit using data. The model is of the form:

\begin{gather}
y_t = -\lambda r_t + \theta a_t + \varepsilon_1 \\ \\
\pi_t = \pi_{t-1} + w y_t + \varepsilon_2 \\ \\
a_t = -\alpha r_t + \varepsilon_3 \\ \\
r_t = \phi_1 \pi_1 + \phi_2 a_t + \varepsilon_4
\end{gather}

where $\varepsilon_i$ are i.i.d. Gaussian shocks. This model has matrix form:

\begin{gather}
 \begin{bmatrix} y_t \\ \pi_t \\ a_t \\ r_t \end{bmatrix}
 =
  \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & \theta & -\lambda \\
   w & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & -\alpha \\
   0 & \phi_1 & \phi_2 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix} y_t \\ \pi_t \\ a_t \\ r_t \end{bmatrix} +
   \begin{bmatrix}
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{bmatrix}
   \begin{bmatrix} y_{t-1} \\ \pi_{t-1} \\ a_{t-1} \\ r_{t-1} \end{bmatrix} +
   \begin{bmatrix} \varepsilon_1 \\ \varepsilon_2 \\ \varepsilon_3 \\ \varepsilon_4 \end{bmatrix}
\end{gather}

i.e.

$$
Y_t = A Y_t + B Y_{t-1} + E 
$$

For estimating this model, assume we have a $4 \times N$ matrix of time series data for $y_t, \pi_t, a_t, r_t$ (call it $D$).

**How do I fit this model using maximum likelihood estimation? (without using Kalman filters or Bayesian methods)**

If $I-A$ is invertible, I can presumably use the reduced form model, but I'm still unsure how to proceed.

My understanding is that this is an "Errors-in-variables" problem, which in some cases requires Total Least Squares (TLS). However, the TLS methods I've seen apply to more simple scaler $y=\beta x + \gamma$ problems, rather than VARs (or structural VARs).

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563473/mle-on-structural-var